# How to connect wsdl api using php

Tags: php, xml, api, soap

Here is my code, and I can't figure out why it's not working.

```
$soapUrl = "http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl";

$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Header><wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-17855236" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:Username>xxx</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxx</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soap:Header><soap:Body xmlns:ns2="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"><ns2:OTA_AirAvailRQ EchoToken="11868765275150-1300257933" PrimaryLangID="en-us" SequenceNmbr="1" Target="LIVE" TimeStamp="2018-10-08T11:39:35" Version="20061.00"><ns2:POS><ns2:Source TerminalID="Farhath/Farhath"><ns2:RequestorID ID="WSBENZTRAVELS" Type="4" /><ns2:BookingChannel Type="12" /></ns2:Source></ns2:POS><ns2:OriginDestinationInformation><ns2:DepartureDateTime>2018-10-30T00:00:00</ns2:DepartureDateTime><ns2:OriginLocation LocationCode="CMB" /><ns2:DestinationLocation LocationCode="RUH" /></ns2:OriginDestinationInformation><ns2:OriginDestinationInformation><ns2:DepartureDateTime>2018-11-30T00:00:00</ns2:DepartureDateTime><ns2:OriginLocation LocationCode="RUH" /><ns2:DestinationLocation LocationCode="CMB" /></ns2:OriginDestinationInformation><ns2:TravelerInfoSummary><ns2:AirTravelerAvail><ns2:PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1" /></ns2:AirTravelerAvail></ns2:TravelerInfoSummary></ns2:OTA_AirAvailRQ></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';

$headers = array(

"Host: airarabia.isaaviations.com",
"Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
"Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_post_string)
); 

$url = $soapUrl;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
$response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);

$parser = simplexml_load_string($response);

print_r($parser);
```

I am able to connect to the API, but couldn't get a result.

Do you have any idea, any solution ?

Comment: Please format your post, so that all of the given code is readable for human eyes. If you 've done that, just have a look at the PHP [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) class. Did you use the search function? The WSSE Header with PHP Soap Client was asked and solved several times before here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a class that helps to simplify generating SOAP XML for a [Laravel package](https://github.com/mtownsend5512/collection-xml). Here is the class:

```
<?php

namespace Mtownsend\CollectionXml\Soap;

use SoapClient;

/**
 * Use the SoapFactory class to build a valid SOAP request
 * but prevent it from making an actual request
 * and capture the data it builds for use.
 */
class SoapFactory extends SoapClient
{
    public $soapRequest;
    public $soapLocation;
    public $soapAction;
    public $soapVersion;

    public function __construct($wsdl, $options)
    {
        parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
    }

    /**
     * Build the SOAP xml string
     * @param  array  $soapRootAndXml [$soapRoot => $xml]
     * @return Mtownsend\CollectionXml\Soap\SoapFactory
     */
    public function build(array $soapRootAndXml)
    {
        $this->ProcessXMLRequest($soapRootAndXml);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Override the SoapClient __doRequest method.
     */
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
    {
        $this->soapRequest = $request;
        $this->soapLocation = $location;
        $this->soapAction = $action;
        $this->soapVersion = $version;
        return ''; // Return a string value or the SoapClient throws an exception
    }

    /**
     * A proxy for the getSoapRequest method.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSoapXml()
    {
        return $this->getSoapRequest();
    }

    /**
     * Return the SOAP request XML.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSoapRequest()
    {
        return $this->soapRequest;
    }

    /**
     * Return the SOAP request location url.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSoapLocation()
    {
        return $this->soapLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Return the SOAP request action.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSoapAction()
    {
        return $this->soapAction;
    }

    /**
     * Return the SOAP request version number.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSoapVersion()
    {
        return $this->soapVersion;
    }
}
```

If you would like to use it, save the contents to `SoapFactory.php` and include it in your script.

Next, get your raw xml ready. **Don't try to SOAPify it or anything**.  Store it in a variable `$xml_post_string`.

You may need to change your soap root if it doesn't work. I've connected to soap endpoints in the past that use 'xmlBody'.

```
$soapRoot = 'xmlBody';

$soapFactory = new SoapFactory($soapUrl, ['trace' => 1]));

$soapXml = $soapFactory->build([$soapRoot => $xml_post_string])->getSoapXml();
```

Now you can try a curl call.

```
$headers = array(

"Host: airarabia.isaaviations.com",
"Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
"Content-Length: ".strlen($soapXml)
); 

$url = $soapUrl;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soapXml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$parser = simplexml_load_string($response);

print_r($parser);
```

There's no guarantee with SOAP, but try that and see if it gets you anywhere.